# Find & replace in a Word Document Footer

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I've VBA code in Excel that edits and modifies Word files.

I'm now trying to find and replace text in the footer of the Word files. I cannot figure out the commands to step through the storyranges of a Word file.

I get

> Argument Not Optional

with Find highlighted.

```
Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Raw\Template\" &  strFile, ReadOnly:=True)
...
Dim myStoryRange As Range
For Each myStoryRange In wrdDoc.StoryRanges
    myStoryRange.Find.Execute FindText:=strField, ReplaceWith:=strValue, Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Wrap:=wdFindContinue
Next myStoryRange
```

Comment: the logic of `.Find.Execute` is absolutely correct. what if you open document in `ReadOnly:=False` state??

Comment: I still receive the "Argument Not Optional" error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, at least for my document.

`wrdDoc.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Find.Execute FindText:=strField, Format:=False, ReplaceWith:=strValue, Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Wrap:=wdFindContinue`

I also had to move the line to an earlier part of my code to work, as for some reason the strField values I was looking to replace within the footer never "made it" to that line in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Right, so after LOADS of failure in doing what others have been trying here's what worked for me. My goal is to replace a string in a word header with Super simple:

```
WordDoc.Sections(1).Headers(1).Range.Find.Execute FindText:=TagName,
 Format:=False,
 ReplaceWith:=TagValue,
 Replace:=wdReplaceAll,
 Wrap:=wdFindContinue
```

Posting for those who come across this feed with similar needs.

Comment: Very similar to my answer, I'm wondering what the difference between  

Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary)
  
and
  
Headers(1)
  
is?

Comment: I have no earthly idea to be honest, but my method exactly replicated with that small change doesn't work in my instance... Might be a version difference, perhaps? I'm using 2013 office products.